# BroadcastReceiver em notificações

Tags: android

Eae galera sou novato na questão de android estou com a seguinte duvida

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que manda notificações todos os dias em horários determinados pelo usuário porem eu não achei conteúdo na internet sobre isso apenas alguns videos mas que estão muito ruins .
Em meio as minhas pesquisas me deparei com o BroadcastReceiver so que nao sei implementar ele se alguem poder me ajudar nisso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A documentação dos *Broadcasts* está [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). Dentro da página possui implementações exemplares.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Action: " + intent.getAction() + "\n");
        sb.append("URI: " + intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toString() + "\n");
        String log = sb.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, log);
        Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```